# Form Validation passed but Model validation Failed and still the error is showing at form. Can anyone explain?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model Books with one field 'name' and i have set max_length to 10.

```
class Books(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

However, in the modelform BookForm i have defined the max_length to 20.

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
 name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
 class Meta:
    fields = ['name']
    model = Books
```

Now while submitting the form with more than 10 length it gives me error saying that the field can at most 10 characters.

```
def book(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    fm = BookForm(data=request.POST)
    print(fm.is_valid())
    print(fm)
    if fm.is_valid():
        fm.save()
    return render(request, 'enroll/books.html', {'form':fm})
  fm = BookForm()
  return render(request, 'enroll/books.html', {'form':fm})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftlAH.png)
Can anyone explain why this is happening and any specific article or link where i can read how the model form and models work with each other in terms of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model form will automatically define the fields based on your Model and its constraints. Since you have defined a name field with max_length validation in Model, you don't require to give it in the form.

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    fields = ['name']
    model = Books
```